# unable to run a sql scrip in mysql workbench after connection

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

After I connect to MySQL workbench and try to run a sql scrip, I see this error!
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have connection so I dont have problem with connection. but just cant run a schema!

Comment: I can't understand what you are doing. You start workbench, which is an IDE for mysql . You connect to the mysql server by choosing one connection and then you do what. start a new query tab ?

Comment: then when I go to FILE to run a sql script , I see this error!

Comment: i tried to open the file instead of run, because this is a hug file , all data did not insert in MYSQL workbench so i have to run this script!

Comment: With big files, don't use workbench. use the command prompt instead. mysql.exe -u root -p mypassword mydatabase < importfile.sql

Comment: thank you for your time. i found that the problem was a special character in my password.